# PHP mail sending empty mails

Tags: php, html

I'm similar to php and don't undestand what is the problem.

Sometimes php function send me empty messages like

*Vanema nimi

Lapse nimi:

Linn:

Telefoninumber:

Email:

Sünnikuupäev:

Sõnumi tekst:*

But it should be filled with values like this

*Vanema nimi test

Lapse nimi: test

Linn: test

Telefoninumber: test

Email: test@test

Sünnikuupäev: 21313

Sõnumi tekst:test*

Here is my php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Обратная Связь</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['parent'])) {$parent = $_POST['parent'];}
      if (isset($_POST['child'])) {$child = $_POST['child'];}
      if (isset($_POST['contacts'])) {$contacts = $_POST['contacts'];}
      if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
      if (isset($_POST['bbd'])) {$bbd = $_POST['bbd'];}
      if (isset($_POST['city'])) {$city = $_POST['city'];}
      if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}
 
      $to = "info@test.ee"; /*Укажите ваш адрес электоронной почты*/
      $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; text/html; charset=utf-8";
      $subject = "Kontakti Info";
      $message = "Vanema nimi $parent \n Lapse nimi: $child \nLinn: 
      $city \nTelefoninumber: $contacts \nEmail: $email \nSünnikuupäev: $bbd \nSõnumi tekst: $mess";
      $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
      if ($send == 'true')
        {
        echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
        echo "<a href=index.php>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу";
        }
      else 
        {
        echo "<p><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!";
        } 
    ?>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
  header('Location: https://test.ee/aitah.html ');
?>
```

Please give me advice what is wrong.

Comment: Can you var_dump every variable to see the content. And `if ($send == 'true')` should be `if ($send){}`

Comment: You can make sending the email depended on having content in the variables you want to send. For instance: `if (isset($email)) { .... send ..... }`.

Comment: can you send me example what to do @KIKOSoftware

Comment: what you mean @executable

Comment: You need to check if  `$_POST` contains value. You can try something like `if (isset($_POST['parent']) and isset($_POST['child']) and isset($_POST['contacts']) and isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['bbd']) and isset($_POST['city']) and isset($_POST['mess'])){
    //Code sending mail
}`What is the output of `var_dump($_POST['parent']);` for example ?

Comment: I agree with the above comments - your code sends the email regardless of whether the form fields were actually filled or not. If you want to ensure all the details are completed you should structure the test like executable suggests. As for why those fields are empty...we can't answer that without seeing your form.

Comment: @executable `mail()` returns boolean true or false, `if($send === true)` would be the "purist" check. If `'true'` is quoted, it's just a regular string. Since OP's checking == loosely though, this will actually work! `var_dump('true' == true); // => bool(true).` Also, `var_dump('false' == true); // => bool(true)`. On `isset`,  one could do `isset($_POST['parent'], $_POST['child'] ...` to keep it a bit more readable, since _"If multiple parameters are supplied then isset()will return true only if all of the parameters are considered set"_. (N.B. An empty field _is set_ as `""`.)

Answer (score 4):

If your script is a form processor only, you could e.g. add `if(empty($_POST)) { die('No form data!'); }` to the top to prevent it from running, except in response to a form submission.

If you require all fields to be filled in, you will have to check each of them before you process your email. You could cram all of those `isset`s into one monster `if(isset(...)` statement. However, there's a simpler and more readable way to do it. First, let's set up a couple of variables:

```
// Your required fields:
$fields = ['parent', 'child', 'contacts', 'email', 'bbd', 'city', 'mess'];
// Your data is collected here:
$data = [];
// Any errors are collected here:
$errors = [];
```

Then, we loop over the fields and if values exist, add to `$data`, otherwise we add an error note.

```
// Loop to check your required fields:

foreach($fields as $field) {
    // If value exists, add to $data:
    if(!empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $data[$field] = $_POST[$field];
    }
    // Else add error:
    else {
        $errors[] = 'Missing field: ' . $field;
    }
}

if(empty($errors)) {
    // No errors, send your email
    // You can use "Vanema nimi {$data['parent']}...",
    // ... otherwise: extract($data) to use $parent etc.
}
else {
    // You could report those errors, or redirect back to the form, or whatever.
}
```

If there are errors (= missing fields), e-mails won't be sent. As a bonus, you now have a *reusable piece of code* that you can use for other forms with similar functionality simply by modifying the `$fields` array. (Wrapping it into a function is a good idea if you do need to reuse it; don't copy-paste code. `function x($post, $fields) { ... }` for a basic helper function.)

Note that here we are using `empty` in place of `isset`. If a blank form is submitted, the fields *are set* (to empty strings `""`). Also note that [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `true` for anything that equals `false` (ie. `""`, `0`, `false`, `null`, `[]`). (*If "0" is an expected and acceptable value, be aware of its "emptiness"!*) On the other hand, [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns true for anything not `null`.

P.S. If your code above is the complete code, and your script simply processes the form data and redirects, then you don't really need the HTML wrapper at all. It will never be displayed.